# How do I get Windows 10 to stop asking me for a pin?

Tags: windows, windows-10, pin

Every time I log in my computer asks me to set a pin. I already have a password set and don't want to set a pin. How do I get Windows 10 to stop asking me for a pin?

Comment: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/99183-enable-disable-pin-reset-sign-windows-10-a.html or maybe https://www.top-password.com/blog/disable-pin-login-in-windows-10-8/ for some starting points potentially.